# Amount of Data transferred out in mongorestore

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I'm using MongoDB version 4

Consider I have a database with dataSize 15GB, storageSize 10GB.
After I `mongodump --gzip` it, the file created is of 5GB.

Now, If I'm restoring it to a remote machine (M2), using `mongorestore` on my workstation (M1), will the data transferred out of M1 be around 5GB or 10GB or 15GB?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB 3.4 and newer servers can [negotiate network compression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.compression.compressors) if MongoDB clients/drivers have also been updated to support the compressed message format. Network compression was introduced as an optional feature in MongoDB 3.4 and is enabled by default for MongoDB 3.6+ servers.

Unfortunately the `mgo` driver used by `mongodump` (as at MongoDB 4.0) does not support network compression and is no longer actively maintained. The expected outcome is that `mongorestore` or `mongodump` data transfer will roughly match your `dataSize` (plus some network overhead).

An officially supported MongoDB Go driver is [currently in development](https://engineering.mongodb.com/post/considering-the-community-effects-of-introducing-an-official-golang-mongodb-driver) and will include full support for the latest MongoDB features. Once the new Go driver is ready, the server command line tools will be updated to be able to take advantage of additional options. A relevant issue to upvote/watch in the MongoDB issue tracker is [TOOLS-1668](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-1668) (*Support wire protocol compression in mongodump and mongorestore*).

In the interim there are a few possible workarounds if network compression will significantly improve your transfer time to a remote server:

- Copy the gzipped `mongodump` file to your remote server and restore locally
- Use an SSH or VPN connection which supports network compression

Comment: I'm planning to restore on ATLAS, so cannot copy the file there and locally restore.
They have some migration methods in their docs, but I thought this would be the easiest if the data transfer is less

Comment: @DushyantBangal In the case of a managed service you are limited to the options provided. With MongoDB Atlas you could use [live migration](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/import/live-import/) or `mongorestore`, but both of those approaches will have similar network requirements at the moment.